# inserting file path into database removes \

Tags: java, filechooser

I am new to java. I want to insert the file path chosen from `FileChooser` into database. But when I try to do so, the path is correct until the query statement, and after entering it into database, it removes all the backslashes present in the filepath.

```
filepath=f.getCanonicalPath();
// some database statements....
String query="insert into table1 values('" + filepath + "')";
```

If my chosen file path is:

> "C:\users\documents\hello.txt";

It inserts it as:

> "C:Usersdocumentshello.txt"

Comment: can you show us more of your code? I believe usage of `StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql` or proper prepare/bind/execute java code would solve your problem

Comment: @Najzero: You shouldn't need to *escape* anything if you use parameterized SQL appropriately.

Comment: @JonSkeet thats correct. Changed it to or - and binding/parameterizing the queries is the prefered way - edit, this misses a bobby tables reference.

Answer (score 9):

Basically, you shouldn't be putting your value directly into SQL like that.

You should use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and set the *parameter* with your value. No escaping required, and no risk of SQL injection attacks.

```
String query = "insert into table1 values(?)";

PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
try {
   statement.setString(1, filePath);
   statement.executeUpdate();
} finally {
   statement.close();
}
```

*Any* time you find yourself building SQL dynamically based on user input, you should take a step back and *strongly* consider parameterized SQL instead. (The exception being if your app is basically a SQL development tool...)

Comment: Jon Skeet i am using mysql so, PreparedStatement showing its under java.sql package

Comment: @user2057804: The `java.sql` package is the common JDBC interface which the MySQL driver will support. Using MySQL is *not* a reason not to use PreparedStatement.

Comment: Thank you all for the immediate responses. My special Thanks to [Najzero](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1563305/najzero) for letting me to know about **StringEscapeUtils** which helped at last which is easy too. :)

Comment: @user2057804: But it's the *wrong fix*. Honestly, you should *absolutely* be using `PreparedStatement`. It shouldn't be hard to do.